# compare() method should not be used for comparing two strings because it just returns the number of characters of first string over second string

Tags: c#, string, compare

I have just figured out that string.compare() is returning
0: when first string content is exactly matching with second string including length.
+ve value: when first string length is more than second irrespective of whether first string present in second string or not.
-ve value: when first string length is not more than second irrespective of whether first string present in second string or not.

Is it good to use compare() method for comparing two strings irrespective of culture.

Can any one suggest me.

Comment: from msdn: Compares substrings of two specified String objects, ignoring or honoring their case and using culture-specific information to influence the comparison, and returns an integer that indicates their relative position in the sort order.

Comment: Don’t figure out anything, read the documentation. What compare returns has very little to do with the length of the compared strings. What do `”A”.CompareTo(“ZZZ”)` and `”AAA”.CompareTo(“Z”)` return?

Comment: What is your question? "Is it good" are subjective questions which are off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> compare method should not be used for comparing two strings because it just returns the number of characters of first string over second string

Say again? Where did you ever get the idea that string comparison works that way? Your belief on how `Compare` works is absolutely wrong.

`string.Compare(s1, s2)` will return:

- `0` if `s1` is neither greater nor smaller than `s2`, that is, considering the comparison criteria chosen, they are both equal orderwise.
- `-1` if `s1` is greater than `s2`: “Z” is greater than “A” and its also greater than “AA”.
- `1` if `s2` is greater than `s1`

Now, when it comes to string comparison criteria’s, you’ve got a few options. Check the documentation to see which one applies to your current requirements.